# Division with numpy matrices that might result in nan

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, division, divide-by-zero

How can I divide two numpy matrices `A` and `B` in python when sometimes the two matrices will have 0 on the same cell?

Basically `A[i,j]>=B[i,j]` for all `i`, `j`. I need to calculate `C=A/B`. But sometimes `A[i,j]==B[i,j]==0`. And when this happens I need `A[i,j]/B[i,j]` to be defined as 0.

Is there a simple pythonic way other than going through all the indexes?

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.divide.html

and 

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html#numpy.seterr

for error handling.

Comment: Could be a possible duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34257436/after-division-by-0-replace-nan-with-0-in-numpy-arrays

Comment: Possible duplicate of [After division by 0, replace NaN with 0 in numpy arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34257436/after-division-by-0-replace-nan-with-0-in-numpy-arrays)

Comment: Are there negative values in `A` or `B`?

Comment: no negative values, thanks for asking @MSeifert

Comment: In that case it's even easier because `A[i, j] == 0` implies that `B[i, j] == 0`. So you only need to do the division on the places where `A[i, j] != 0`. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html#optional-keyword-arguments) argument for ufuncs like [`np.true_divide`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.true_divide.html):

```
np.true_divide(A, B, where=(A!=0) | (B!=0))
```

In case you have no negative values (as stated in the comments) and `A >= B` for each element (as stated in the question) you can simplify this to:

```
np.true_divide(A, B, where=(A!=0))
```

because `A[i, j] == 0` implies `B[i, j] == 0`.

---

For example:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.random.randint(0, 3, (4, 4))
B = np.random.randint(0, 3, (4, 4))
print(A)
print(B)
print(np.true_divide(A, B, where=(A!=0) | (B!=0)))

[[1 0 2 1]
 [1 0 0 0]
 [2 1 0 0]
 [2 2 0 2]]

[[1 0 1 1]
 [2 2 1 2]
 [2 1 0 1]
 [2 0 1 2]]

[[ 1.   0.   2.   1. ]
 [ 0.5  0.   0.   0. ]
 [ 1.   1.   0.   0. ]
 [ 1.   inf  0.   1. ]]
```

---

As alternative: Just replace `nan`s after the division:

```
C = A / B          # may print warnings, suppress them with np.seterrstate if you want
C[np.isnan(C)] = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a mask with [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to choose between such a case of `A and B being both zeros` and otherwise and put out `0` or an elementwise division respectively -

```
from __future__ import division # For Python 2.x

mask = (A == B) & (A==0)
C = np.where(mask, 0, A/B)
```

About the mask creation : `(A==B)` would be the mask of all elements that are equal between `A` and `B` and with `(A==0)` we have a mask of all elements that are zero in `A`. Thus, with a combined mask of `(A == B) & (A==0)`, we have mask of places where both `A` and `B` are zeros. A more simpler version to do the same task and maybe easier to understand would be to check for zeros in both `A` and `B` and it would be :

```
mask = (A==0) & (B==0)
```

About the use of `np.where`, its syntax is :

```
C = np.where(mask, array1, array2)
```

i.e. we would select elements for assinging into `C` based on the mask. If the corresponding mask element is `True`, we pick the corresponding element from `array1`, else from `array2`. This is done on elementwise level and thus, we have the output `C`.

Sample run -

```
In [48]: A
Out[48]: 
array([[4, 1, 4, 0, 3],
       [0, 4, 1, 4, 3],
       [1, 0, 0, 4, 0]])

In [49]: B
Out[49]: 
array([[4, 2, 2, 1, 4],
       [2, 1, 2, 4, 2],
       [4, 0, 2, 0, 3]])

In [50]: mask = (A == B) & (A==0)

In [51]: np.where(mask, 0, A/B)
Out[51]: 
array([[ 1.  ,  0.5 ,  2.  ,  0.  ,  0.75],
       [ 0.  ,  4.  ,  0.5 ,  1.  ,  1.5 ],
       [ 0.25,  0.  ,  0.  ,   inf,  0.  ]])
```

Comment: this is why I love stackoverflow. Answers that I don't even understand. What does this: mask = (A == B) & (A==0) do?

Comment: @PietroSperoni Added some comments into the post. Hope to make sense with those.

Comment: Ok, so the mask is basically a matrix of true and false that indicate where to pick the first or the second.

Comment: I probably just need "mask = (B==0)"

Comment: Yeah, if you want to take care of only those cases. I assumed both, as I carried that from the question - `"sometimes the two matrices will have 0 on the same cell"`.